# Copiar coluna de tabela A para tabela B sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa tarde Pessoal,

Tenho duas tabelas e preciso fazer um SELECT para vincular o código das cidades que estão na tabela B com as cidades da tabela A.

Estou usando a query:

```
select
  a.Cidade,
  b.Cidade,
  b.cod
from
  tabelaA a left join tabelaB b on (a.cidade = b.cidade)
```

[image: Exemplo do que gostaria:]

por favor, poderia ajudar, obrigado.

utilizo o banco SQL SERVER 2017 Express

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Olá c3s1, bem vindo ao SOpt! Podemos ajudar sim. Poderia esclarecer em que parte está tendo dificuldade? Aparentemente o seu select faz o que você precisa. Poderia ser mais específico com o que espera?

Comment: @JoséDiz - cometi um erro, na verdade a tabela A tem 'N' numero de cidades, e se repetem varias vezes, sendo que duas cidades podem ter o mesmo nome em estados diferentes, por isso minha consulta retornava uma quantidade maior de registros, resolvi comparante nao so a cidade, mas tambem o estado em que cada cidade pertence, deu certo com a query acima mesmo, so adicionei a comparação de cidade por estado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVIDO !!! Na verdade a tabela A tem 'N' numero de cidades, e se repetem varias vezes, sendo que duas cidades podem ter o mesmo nome em estados diferentes, por isso minha consulta retornava uma quantidade maior de registros, resolvi comparante nao so a cidade, mas tambem o estado em que cada cidade pertence, deu certo com a query acima mesmo, so adicionei a comparação de cidade por estado. Obrigado.